# Is 「子供を映画へ連れて行く約束した」 ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

> 子供を映画へ連れて行く約束をした。
>
> > I promised to take my child to a movie.

Here's my parsing:

子供を映画へ連れて行く | relative clause

約束をした | verb phrase

We need a noun in order for it to be modified by a relative clause, so we cannot use 約束する because it's a verb. Therefore, a literal translation for the above would be "I made the promise to take my child to a movie."

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26120/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4007/9831 /

Comment: What you are asking would be clearer if you included the sentence without を in your question, not only in the title.

Comment: FYI: [what does と mean in 貴方を呼ばないと約束するから](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66370/43676)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify 約束 using a relative clause (or any other noun-modifying expressions), を is mandatory at least in formal sentences. As you said, 約束する without を is a verb, and thus cannot be modified by a noun-modifying expression.

---

**を is mandatory** (modifiers are applied to the noun 約束):

- 大事な約束**を**した
- 旅行の約束**を**した
- 子供を映画へ連れて行く約束**を**した

<sup>(を may be dropped anyway in informal conversations.)</sup>

**を is optional** (modifiers are applied to the verb phrase 約束(を)する):

- 昨日約束(を)した
- 確かに約束(を)した
- 子供を映画へ連れて行くよう約束(を)した

---

See Chocolate's comment for details.